Choose location to write to, within macro with mouse click
I have a simple Excel file I use to clean up cell entries, the final cell needs to be copied and pasted with paste/special/"Values" to a different Workbook, Worksheet, and Cell.
Ever time I run the Macro, the results need to go to a different Cell and there will or may be different worksheets or workbooks also.
It needs to copy Cell F6 of Workbook containing the Macro, wait for the cell selection of recipient cell and paste the value of the copied data there upon mouse selection.
This code works but without the freedom to choose the final cell, I need help with:
Range("F6").Select needs to also point to workbook containing the Macro.
Windows("test.xlsx").Activate and Range("B2").Select.  How do I make these a Selectable by mouse click?
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Range("F6").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("test.xlsx").Activate
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    
End Sub




Use the InputBox function to display a dialog that allows the user to select a cell on the destination sheet.

Sub demo()
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, desWk As Workbook, desCell As Range
    Set srcSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  ' modify sheet name as needed
    On Error Resume Next
    Set desWk = Workbooks("test.xlsx")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If desWk Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Please open test.xlsx before run the code." 
    Else
        desWk.Activate
        On Error Resume Next
        Set desCell = Application.InputBox("Please select a cell to paste", Type:=8)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If desCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Please select a cell."
        Else
            With desCell.Cells(1)
                .Value = srcSht.Range("F6").Value
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
                .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
                .WrapText = True
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .MergeCells = False
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub


thank you, it does work. Is there any way to have variables for workbook and worksheet?

thank you, it does work. But is there any way to have variables for workbook and worksheet?  For example, I have 3 workbooks open.  I need to run the macro 1st for WB "A" SH 2 Cell F5, then 2nd for WB B SH 4 Cell A10. Can choosing a the destination cell set the WB and WS in the macro?
